# Low power, seven segment display

Tags: low-power, display, 7segmentdisplay, coin-cell

I want to display a 4 digit number on a small device that fits in a hand.
I have a CR2032 3V battery at around 230mA, my microprocessor is a 8051 (in a [BLE112](http://www.glynstore.com/content/docs/bluegiga/BLE112_Datasheet.pdf)) usually uses about 0.9µA and I want the device to last as long as possible.

I've looked at the typical seven segment displays, which typically uses a few mA which is too much.

A alternative is the Sharp [LS013B7DH01](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/365/LS013B7DH01_16_AUG_10-197624.pdf) which is used in Pebble and uses 5 µA, but seems a bit complex for my microprocessor (and expensive)?

There should be some simple low power 7 segment display which has a average power consumption measured in µA (not mA), but I simply can't find it or think of some other solution.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: How often does the value change?

Comment: When in use, a few times per minute

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LCD display without back-light is the only possible solution on these conditions.

Something like this:

[image]

Here is some example data sheet: [Link to PDF](http://store.comet.bg/download-file.php?id=2583)

Comment: Nice, how much energy would it use?

Comment: @Hink - probably several uA.

Comment: How would I drive it with a 3V (DC) coincell battery in a power efficient way? I found out that I need some separate driver chip which can alternate the current. Preferably I would like to just input numbers via SPI, I2C etc.

Comment: @Hink - with programmable unit as a uC you can control it in whatever manner you want. For 4 digit number you will need 7+4=11 outputs.

Comment: But every LCD display I could find uses AC. As I understand it, all need some controller to alternate the current for it to work with DC? Is there a tutorial using a LCD segment display like the one you show in the picture?

Comment: @Hink - but you can generate AC with the outputs of the uC. But IMO, how to do so is a little bit offtopic in this answer. Maybe you have to ask another question about how to control LCD display.

Comment: Note that you need a minimum of 1 + (7 * 4) = 29 outputs to drive a static 7-segment 4-digit display (no decimal points or colon) as in the linked datasheet. One output drives the backplane (common) plus you need one for each segment.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Can't shift register help this?

Answer (score 4):

E-paper displays "stick" at the last value displayed, and only use power to change:  http://www.eink.com/

They're a bit of a hassle to drive, and expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Sarkfun used to sell a small E-paper display. 
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10150

Perhaps you can locate a different widget vendor for the same.

Comment: SeeedStudio has these:
http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/small-epaper-shield-p-1597.html

http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/eink-display-shield-p-1374.html